# Playing just one sound android

Tags: android, audio, media-player

i'm developing a little quizz app and i would like to play sound depending on if the user answers the question correctly or not.

I've got many sound files in "assets/".

What I would like to do is to play just one of these sounds.
I've been able to play the sound, but not only one, both sound  (correct and incorrect) are played one after the other.

How can i play just one?
Here's my source:

```
public void audioPlayer(){
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    mp = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        String mp3File = "correct.mp3";
        AssetManager assetMan = getAssets();
        FileInputStream mp3Stream = assetMan.openFd(mp3File).createInputStream();

        mp.setDataSource(mp3Stream.getFD());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your sound files i.e fail and applause in raw folder and use the following code :

```
private AssetFileDescriptor sPlaySoundDescriptor = null;
private AssetFileDescriptor sFailSoundDescriptor = null;
private MediaPlayer mp = null;
public static final int FAIL_SOUND = 1;
public static final int APPLAUSE_SOUND = 2;

public void audioPlayer(int soundType){
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    AssetFileDescriptor soundFileDescriptor = null;
    try {
        if (sFailSoundDescriptor == null) {
            sFailSoundDescriptor = context.getResources().
                    openRawResourceFd(R.raw.fail);
        }
        if (sApplauseSoundDescriptor == null) {
            sApplauseSoundDescriptor = context.getResources().
                    openRawResourceFd(R.raw.applause);
        }
        switch (soundType) {
            case FAIL_SOUND:
                soundFileDescriptor = sFailSoundDescriptor;
                break;
            case APPLAUSE_SOUND:
                soundFileDescriptor = sApplauseSoundDescriptor;
                break;
        }
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(soundFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                        soundFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(),
                        soundFileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
                player.seekTo(0);
                player.start();
            }
        });  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```